# Simple prediction model for multiple features

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, prediction

I am new in prediction models. I am currently using python2.7 and sklearn. I would like to know a simple model to combine many features to predict one target.

To make it more clear. Lets say I have 4 arrays of size 10: A,B,C,Y. I would like to use the values of A,B,C to predict the values of Y.

Thank you

Comment: That describes just about every regression problem. What is a good model depends on your data and how you intend to use it.

Comment: I just need a simple one. A linear model will do. The thing is that the ones I have found until now (eg. LinearRegression()) use only 2 parameters, A,Y,  and I want it for more dimensions.

Comment: I tried passing a multi dimensional one and I get this in return
ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.

Comment: `A` should be an m×n by matrix with `m` values of `n` dimensions.

Comment: If i transform the matrix into mxn I get: "ValueError: shapes (5,1) and (2,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)"

Comment: Sorry @DonReba you are right. The errors pop up from the functions that calculate the error not the regression coefficients. Thank you.